# Importing SketchUp (skp) file to ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, 3d, sketchup

I've downloaded some 3D data from 3dwarehouse.sketchup.com

Now, I would like to open it in ArcGIS Pro but I cannot find how can to do it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain new phrasing instead of creating a new question.

Comment: ArcGIS Pro and 3D Analyst is required https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/import-3d-files.htm

Answer (score 0):

The [Supported formats with the Data Interoperability extension](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/data-interoperability/supported-formats-with-the-data-interoperability-extension.htm) suggests that SKP (Google SketchUp and Trimble SketchUp) files can be read and written using ArcGIS Pro with that extension.

I have not yet tested this.